# Missing data when exporting to excel using Laravel Maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, maatwebsite-excel

I'm exporting data from database to excel and downloading the file. It works but for some reason the "username" data is missing. Any ideas? First time using Laravel Excel. Thanks.

[image: Data User table image]

[image: Downloaded excel image]

**UserExport.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;
use App\data;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;


class UsersExport implements FromCollection,WithHeadings
{
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
*/
public function collection()
{
    return data::select(['username', 'password', 'email', 'phone'])->get();
}

public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        'Username',
        'Password',
        'Email',
        'Phone'
    ];
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function exportExcel()
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

**Data.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class data extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['username','password','email','phone'];

protected $table = 'user';
protected $primaryKey = 'username';
public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Comment: may I see the contents of your `App\data`? @stalwart1014

Comment: What is `data` here?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy check edit

Comment: @JueViole17 check edit

Comment: Have you checked the output of the `collection()` method to see if it contains the data? What is the result if you return `data::all()` from the `collection()` method?

Comment: On another note, your class naming isn't consistent. You capitalise `UsersExport` but not `data` .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of encapsulating your desired columns in an array

```
public function collection()
{
    return data::select(['username', 'password', 'email', 'phone'])->get();
}
```

Try changing it into this

```
public function collection()
{
    return data::select('username', 'password', 'email', 'phone')->get();
}
```

Comment: still the same.